# Reporting Services Excel export very slow

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report, producing about 32 000 rows of data with no funny formats, just a table with about 55 columns.  When I run the report on the server, it renders in about 10 seconds, and exports in about another 10.  When I run this report from the report portal in my machine's browser, it takes about a minute to render, and another 5 minutes to export.  Is there something I can check or does the fact that it's processing a lot faster on the server point to it being network related?  The server is an Azure VM in Europe and I'm in South Africa.

Comment: not sure what you mean here. you say "When you run the report on the server is takes 10 seconds", but then say when you view it in the report portal it takes a minute. The portal is on the server and the report is run on the server. These statements conflict with each other; does it takes 10 seconds or 1 minute?

Comment: Hi @Larnu , sorry for the confusion.  When I connect to the server via remote desktop, and run the report in the browser on the server, then it's 10 secs.  When I'm not logged onto a remote desktop session and I run it from my laptop, it's 1 minute.

Comment: Is it not the netwrok constraint between your machine and the remote server. The data collection is a round robin on the network and needs a connection. Remember if the connection times out you will get either missing data or no data at all. l would consider looking at the connection

Comment: @TKAY thanks, that's what I was thinking too but it's still pretty annoying.